# azure log search alerts with log messages in the email

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

we write custom logs to appinsights (Structured logging)

Question:
Is there a way to include the all log statements in the email that gets generated via azure custom log alerts ?
or is a webhook/PS script required ?

Thanks -nen

Answer (score -1):

You can use azure logic app services which are useful for automating workflows that connect your apps, data, services, and systems.

Im try to fetch all the log statements from appinsights using `Visualize Analytics query` or `Run Analytics query` action of `Azure Application Insights` Connector just by adding *Connection name, Application Id and API Key.*

[image]

In the next step you can add `Send an email (V2)` action of `Office 365 Outlook` connector and send all the log statements in the email.

Below is the flow of my logic app

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

In my Inbox

[image]

You can also refer to the tutorial from [Automate Azure Application Insights processes by using Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/automate-with-logic-apps)

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Overview for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview)
2. [Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/applicationinsights/)